# Min and max of deviations from mean in Matlab

Tags: matlab, computation

**Intro:** I need to find the    greatest/smallest possible deviations from the average in some given Matlab vectors. The issue is that, due to the large dimensions of the arrays involved, I cannot explicitly construct such vectors. Therefore, I wonder whether there is a smarter way to proceed. I summarise below the procedure that I would implement if there were no memory constraints and then present my question.

**(1)** Consider 28 matrices in Matlab `A{1},..., A{28}`.
For each `j=1,...,28`, `A{j}` has 4 columns. The number of rows of `A{j}` can be different across `j=1,..., 28` and is stored in the vector `r`.

```
clear
rng default
A=cell(28,1);
r=randi(10000,28,1)+10000; %28x1
for j=1:28
    A{j}=randn(r(j),4); %r(j)x4
end
```

**(2)** For each `j=1,...,28`, let `b{j}` be the `r(j) x 1` vector that is obtained by summing the first two rows of `A{j}` and subtracting the last two rows of `A{j}`:

```
b=cell(28,1);
for j=1:28
    b{j}=A{j}(:,1)+A{j}(:,2)-A{j}(:,3)-A{j}(:,4); %r(j)x1
end
```

**(3)** Let `B` be the `R x 28` matrix that is obtained as a 28-D grid from the vectors `b{1},...,b{28}`:

```
%[ca, cb, cc, cd, ce, ...] = ndgrid(b{1}, b{2}, b{3}  , ..., b{28});
%B(:,1)=ca(:);
%B(:,2)=cb(:);
%...
%B(:,28)=...;
c=cell(28,1);
[c{:}]=ndgrid(b{:});
c=cellfun(@(x)x(:),c,'UniformOutput',false);
B=[c{:}];
```

Apologies for the  incomplete code. As you can imagine, this is the step where I have issues as explained below.

**(4)** For each row of `B`, I compute the difference between such row and its mean value and store the results in a `R x 28` matrix `D`:

```
%R=size(B,1);
%D=zeros(R,28);
%for t=1:R
%    D(t,:)=B(t,:)-mean(B(t,:)); 
%end
D=B-mean(B,2);
```

**(5)** For each `j=1,...,28`, I compute the min and max value of `D(:,j)` and store it in a matrix `F`

```
F=zeros(2,28);
for j=1:28
    F(1,j)=min(D(:,j));
    F(2,j)=max(D(:,j));
end
```

**Question:** `F` is the matrix that I would like to construct. However, step (3) is unfeasible due to the large `r(1),..., r(28)`. Even a loop would take forever. Hence, I'm asking: is there a smarter way to construct `F` that saves me from explicitly obtaining `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fast solution (without using `ndgrid`):

```
F = zeros(2,28);
mx = cellfun(@max,b)
mn = cellfun(@min,b)
for k = 1: 28
    F(1,k) = min(b{k}-(b{k}+sum(mx)-mx(k))/28);
    F(2,k) = max(b{k}-(b{k}+sum(mn)-mn(k))/28);
end
```

**Explanation**:

Suppose matrix `B` to be:

```
B =   
   1   3   5
   1   3   6
   1   4   5
   1   4   6
   2   3   5
   2   3   6
   2   4   5
   2   4   6
```

So we want to compute `MinB=min(B-mean(B,2))`. There are 3 columns and `MinB = [MinB(1) MinB(2) MinB(3)]`.
We begin to compute for the first column or `MinB(1)`.
We can split the `B` matrix based on the values of the first column :

```
 B1=  
   1   3   5
   1   3   6
   1   4   5
   1   4   6

 B2= 
   2   3   5
   2   3   6
   2   4   5
   2   4   6
```

so `MinB(1)` can be computed as `min(MinB1(1), MinB2(1))`.
And `MinB1(1)` can be written as: `MinB1(1) = min(1 - mean(B1, 2))`.
Equivalently is can be written as: `MinB1(1) = 1 - max(mean(B1, 2))`.

We can write `mean` as `sum` : `max(mean(B1, 2))== > max(sum(B1,2)/3)`.

Consider all combinations of numbers. Which combination has the maximum `mean` or maximum `sum` ? the combination that contains max of each vector of `b` or `mx=[2 4 6]`.
So we have used `cellfun` to compute `max` for each vector of `b`. This way we don't need to compute the mean of the all combinations we just need to compute `max` for each vector of `b` and then compute the mean of that vector.
That is the key point to the above solution and `max` can also be computed this way.

Comment: I actually computed mean ->  `sum/28`. I should provide an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! It makes a lot of sense now.